# How to return array of user defined types, and then pass as an argument in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-types

I have a User Defined Type, Decision:

```
Public Type Decision
    choice As String
    cost As Double
End Type
```

I am trying to use an array of my UDTs to store the results of a dynamic program (choice and cost for a stage/state).

```
Public Function DPSolve(arg1, arg2, ...) as Decision
        Dim Table() As Decision
        ReDim Table(arg1, arg2+ 1)

        'do stuff that fills each Table().choice and Table().cost

        'return Table()
        DPSolve = Table()
End Function
```

If I want to then pass the result of this function to a new function (to say, print the Table() in Excel, or do more work using the Table() result, how do I do this?

I am trying

```
Sub Main
    Dim x as variant

    x = DPSolve(arg1, arg2, ...)

    Function2(x)
End Main
```

but am getting the following error:
[image: Compile Error]

I have tried making x an array, but I get a "cannot assign to array" error. I have also tried making x a Decision, but that did not work either. The code is in a module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `DPSolve` shall return an array of `Decision`s. And `x()`shall also be an array of `Decision`s.

```
Public Type Decision
    choice As String
    cost As Double
End Type

Public Function DPSolve(arg1, arg2) As Decision()
        Dim Table() As Decision
        ReDim Table(arg1, arg2 + 1)

        'do stuff that fills each Table().choice and Table().cost

        'return Table()
        DPSolve = Table()
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim x() As Decision

    x = DPSolve(2, 2)

End Sub
```

Works for me. Example:

```
Public Type Decision
    choice As String
    cost As Double
End Type

Public Function DPSolve(arg1, arg2) As Decision()
        Dim Table() As Decision
        ReDim Table(arg1, arg2 + 1)

        'do stuff that fills each Table().choice and Table().cost

        Table(1, 2).choice = "choice1,2"
        Table(1, 2).cost = 123.45

        'return Table()
        DPSolve = Table()
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim x() As Decision

    x = DPSolve(2, 2)

    MsgBox x(1, 2).choice
    MsgBox x(1, 2).cost


End Sub
```

To be clear with "Can't assign to an array". You can't assign an type and size dimensioned and filled array to another type and size dimensioned array. But you surely can assign an filled array to an type dimensioned but **not** size dimensioned array.

```
Sub test()

 Dim arr1(3) As String
 Dim arr2() As String

 arr1(0) = "Value 0"
 arr1(1) = "Value 1"
 arr1(2) = "Value 2"
 arr1(3) = "Value 3"

 arr2 = arr1

 MsgBox Join(arr2, ", ")

End Sub
```

Comment: I've never understood why MS didn't support casting to Variants of VT_USERDEFINED...

Comment: I tried this, but got a "can't assign to array" error. I don't think you can assign arrays like a1() = a2() in VBA. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264711.aspx

Comment: Sure you have tried exactly that code? `Public Function DPSolve(arg1, arg2) As Decision()` note the parentheses behind `Decision()`.

Comment: @Mark - `x = DPSolve(2, 2)`, not `x() = DPSolve(2, 2)`

Comment: @AxelRichter Putting `DPSolve(arg1, arg2) As Decision()` including the brackets, and `x = DPSolve(2, 2)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error mean that you can't assign a defined type to a variant.
So you either need to have the type defined on the variable

```
Public Type Decision
    choice As String
    cost As Double
End Type

Public Sub DPSolve(source, arg1, arg2)
  ReDim source(arg1, arg2 + 1)
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim x() As Decision
    DPSolve x, 4, 4
End Sub
```

Or if you really want to use a variant, then you need to use a class:

```
Public Sub DPSolve(source, arg1, arg2)
  Dim i&, j&
  ReDim source(0 To arg1, 0 To arg2 + 1) As Decision
  For i = 0 To arg1
    For j = 0 To arg2 + 1
      Set source(i, j) = New Decision
    Next
  Next
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim x
    DPSolve x, 4, 4
End Sub
```

Class Decision:

```
Public choice As String
Public cost As Double
```